# What is the use of LOGGING_FACILITY compared to NSLog in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on creating key pairs for RSA Algorithm. I was looking into Apple's sample project on Crypto, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html

See the below code

```
sanityCheck = SecKeyGeneratePair((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyPairAttr, &publicKey, &privateKey);

LOGGING_FACILITY( sanityCheck == noErr && publicKey != NULL &&     privateKey != NULL, @"Something really bad went wrong with generating the key pair." );
```

I found LOGGING_FACILITY is used. I understand it is used for logging purposes. Can anyone elaborate what is the difference between LOGGING_FACILITY and NSLog? Also show pointers to Apple's documentation explaining on the usage of LOGGING_FACILITY

Comment: I am using Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a) and compile code with LOGGING_FACILITY, build is failing. Xcode spits the below error                      "Implicit declaration of function 'LOGGING_FACILITY' is invalid in C99" Can someone help me understand why do we get this error?